# How to make g++ operator overloading errors more concise?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++, operator-overloading

Every now and again I make an operator overload mistake which causes g++ to generate depressing volumes of impenetrable compiler error messages, consider the following example:

```
int someValue ;
vector <vector <int> > 2d ;
while(2d [i] > someValue) someFunction();
```

Obviously, I'm missing the second index for the '2d' vector. Unfortunately, instead of concisely reporting that it failed to find a match for the 'greater than' operator, g++ lists in lurid detail every single overload candidate which partially matches the comparison operation, including some really nasty ones buried deep in the standard library.

Can anyone provide some insight as to why this is the preferred method for handling overload failures?, is there any option to limit or curtail this compiler output?, thx.

Comment: Are you comparing the vector on ints(2d[i]) to an int(somevalue)?

Comment: Time to switch to clang?

Comment: @H2CO3, g++ still has the edge over clang on high levels of optimsation

Comment: @ahenderson, the intention is to compare 2d [i][j] to int(someValue)

Comment: But in your code example your still using 2d[i] not 2d[i][j]. If that was not a typo your error has to do with `operator>`

Comment: Yes, that's the point, the question is about how to control the response of the compiler to mistakes when applying the overload operator

Comment: I see. sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @GearoidMurphy I know, and I'm a big fan of GCC in fact. Clang is new, so is LLVM, and I'm not sure they are as good as GCC. But using clang is 'trendy' and its error messages are more useful... Anyway, I still use GCC whenever possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [STLFilt](http://www.bdsoft.com/tools/stlfilt.html). However it is not updated for some time.

A good IDE shall have some filtering for this annoying extra errors - at the time I was using Eclipse it had very good filtering - however I do not know how it does this now.

My personal approach is to skip everything I do not understand and concentrate on errors I understand ;)